# 45 degree line and same coordinate lengths in scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I've two datas to compare in a scatter plot.

```
data1 <-c(0.341, 0.655, 0.934, 1.741)
data2 <-c(1.8, 2, 2.4, 2.6)
```

With the code below I am getting this:
[image: graph]

```
plot(data1, data2, main="Minute Max.", asp=1,
      xlab="Historical Values ", ylab="Disaggregated Values", pch=19)
```

I have three wishes:

1) Adding a 45 degree line

[image]

2) Having same coordinate length. For the example above, you can see the max. value is 2.6 in total. So I want my scatter diagram as square. Both x and y coordinates lengths' must be 2.6.

3) I know how to export the plot manually. But which code should I use to export the plot?

Answer (score 6):

1) Use `abline` to draw a straight line. This is called *after* your plot.

```
plot(data)
abline(0,1)
```

`abline()` also takes additional arguments, like `col="red"`.

2) This can be done using `xlim` and `ylim`. For more information on how you can edit the plot, use `?plot()` inside R to see the revelant helpfile.

```
plot(data, xlim=c(0,2.6),ylim=(0,2.6)
```

3) If you want it saved as e.g. a pdf, you can do the following.

```
pdf("myfile.pdf")
plot(data,....)
dev.off()
```

Also works with jpeg, e.g.

```
jpeg("myplot.jpg")
plot(data)
dev.off()
```

Comment: @mhh Thanks for the answer. For the 2nd answer, how can I make the ylim and xlim changing with data. Because I have too much data like these.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thank you for your suggestion, I have edited my answer to `abline(0,1)`.

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi, if you want your x- and ylim to change depending on your data, but always be equal to each other, you could use an expression. E.g. `plot(data,...,xlim=c(min(data),max(data))` and do the same for `ylim`. Be sure to call `min()` and `max()` on the correct data.